# Image to matrix using python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I am required to access all images in a folder and store it in a matrix. I was able to do it using matlab and here is the code:

```
input_dir = 'C:\Users\Karim\Downloads\att_faces\New Folder';
image_dims = [112, 92];

filenames = dir(fullfile(input_dir, '*.pgm'));
num_images = numel(filenames);

images = [];
for n = 1:num_images
    filename = fullfile(input_dir, filenames(n).name);
    img = imread(filename);
    img = imresize(img,image_dims);   
end
```

but I am required to do it using python and here is my python code:

```
import Image
import os
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *
import numpy as np


#import images
dirname = "C:\\Users\\Karim\\Downloads\\att_faces\\New folder"


#get number of images and dimentions
path, dirs, files = os.walk(dirname).next()
num_images = len(files)
image_file = "C:\\Users\\Karim\\Downloads\\att_faces\\New folder\\2.pgm"
im = Image.open(image_file)
width, height = im.size



images = []

for x in xrange(1, num_images):
    filename = os.listdir(dirname)[x]
    img = Image.open(filename)
    img = im.convert('L')
    images[:, x] = img[:]
```

but I am getting this error:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '10.pgm'
although the file is present.

Comment: You need to pass the absolute path of the file in to `Image.open`, unless your cwd is in the same place as the images. `os.path.join(path, filename)` should work.

Comment: @GP89: do you mean that I should replace 'filename = os.listdir(dirname)[x]' by 'filename = os.path.join(dirname, x)'?

Comment: No, the `filename` you get back from the `os.listdir` line will just be "10.pgm" for example. If you just pass that it will look for it in the current directory that the script is run from. Make a new variable `filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)` and pass `filepath` into `Image.open`. You shouldn't get the `IOError` then. This will work because `filepath` value will be an absolute path, `"C:\\Users\\Karim\\Downloads\\att_faces\\New folder\\10.pgm"`

Comment: Also, note that you can use forward slashes for path separators on any platform in python to avoid double-backslashes. E.g. `"C:/path/to/somefile.pgm"`. You can also use a "raw" string, e.g. `r"C:\path\to\somefile.pgm"`.

Comment: Additionally, `images` is a list, not a numpy array, so `images[:,x]` is not what you want.  What you probably intended to do is just `images = [Image.open(fn).convert('L') for fn in filenames]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your end goal is, but try something more like this:

```
import numpy as np
import Image
import glob

filenames = glob.glob('/path/to/your/files/*.pgm')
images = [Image.open(fn).convert('L') for fn in filenames]
data = np.dstack([np.array(im) for im in images])
```

This will yield a width x height x num_images numpy array, assuming that all of your images have the same dimensions.

However, your images will be unsorted, so you may want to do `filenames.sort()`.

Also, you may or may not want things as a 3D numpy array, but that depends entirely on what you're actually doing.  If you just want to operate on each "frame" individually, then don't bother stacking them into one gigantic array.

Comment: I got another error `ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate`

Comment: Have a look at `filenames` (i.e. `print filenames`). It sounds like there aren't any files matching your specified pattern.