# List to array conversion to use ravel() function

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list in python and I want to convert it to an array to be able to use `ravel()` function.

Comment: Please, try to answer requests for clarifications and improve your questions instead of spawning lots of not-really-good questions. Finally, read carefully [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15867578/1191119). I think it solves your big problem...

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Use [`numpy.asarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html):

```
import numpy as np
myarray = np.asarray(mylist)
```

Comment: Actually, `myarray = np.array(mylist)` should be enough.

Comment: well, asarray it's safer as it won't copy arrays but simply return them, so it's a good habit to use it unless one it's sure to wawnt a copy of the original data

Comment: @EnricoGiampieri, fair, but wouldn't you need to get an array out of this no matter what? I guess I don't follow how you wouldn't get either command to generate a new array object.

Comment: both command will create a new array starting from a list, that's for sure, but often the point is to convert an input to a specific format to apply certain method, and this looks more like the case of the OP. using asarray is a good habit unless one is certain that a new copy is needed. simply typing `array` is enough, but why let slip the possibility to educate the OP to some good habit while we are here?

Comment: I just wanted to say that @fgb proposed an adequate solution. the '.asarray' function returns a numpy object whereas '.array returns you an array directly. Anyways, thanks to both of you guys!

Answer (score 7):

## create an int array and a list

```
from array import array
listA = list(range(0,50))
for item in listA:
    print(item)
arrayA = array("i", listA)
for item in arrayA:
    print(item)
```

Comment: what does the "i" stand for ? and what should it be for str ?

Answer (score 6):

I wanted a way to do this without using an extra module. First turn list to string, then append to an array:

```
dataset_list = ''.join(input_list)
dataset_array = []
for item in dataset_list.split(';'): # comma, or other
    dataset_array.append(item)
```

Comment: Not possible to edit a typo: the first row should be `dataset_list = ';'.join(input_list)`

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is calling `ravel` on your (nested, I s'pose?) list, you can do that directly, `numpy` will do the casting for you:

```
L = [[1,None,3],["The", "quick", object]]
np.ravel(L)
# array([1, None, 3, 'The', 'quick', <class 'object'>], dtype=object)
```

Also worth mentioning that [you needn't go through `numpy` at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40813764/7207392).

Answer (score -2):

Use the following code:

```
import numpy as np

myArray=np.array([1,2,4])  #func used to convert [1,2,3] list into an array
print(myArray)
```

Answer (score -13):

if variable b has a list then you can simply do the below:

create a new variable "a" as: `a=[]`
 then assign the list to "a" as: `a=b`

now "a" has all the components of list "b" in array.

so you have successfully converted list to array.

Comment: Actually, no ... this is completely wrong.  All you'll have is two variables pointing at the same list, not a numpy array.