# How can I prepare a numpy.ndarray to pass it to librosa.display.waveshow()?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, wav, librosa

In my code I'm reading a list that stores 44100 samples of a one second wave audio file like this:

```
with open("./test.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    rows = list(reader)
    audiofile = rows[12]
```

If I print the file:

```
print(audiofile)
```

I get this result:

```
' 0.06585693', ' 0.06663513', ' 0.066467285', ' 0.06716919', ' 0.06765747', ' 0.06770325', ' 0.06803894', ' 0.068481445', ' 0.06854248', ' 0.06918335', ' 0.06915283', ' 0.0693512', ' 0.07003784', ' 0.07008362', ' 0.06993103', ' 0.070632935', ' 0.07072449', ' 0.07104492', ' 0.07159424', ' 0.071395874', ...
```

and so on. Meaning the list 'audiofile' contains all the 44100 floating point samples of the wave file just like desired.

Now before I can display the signal with librosa waveshow I need to put the data inside a numpy.ndarray.

I found this solution [Convert list elements into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112274/convert-list-elements-into-array)
here on stack overflow that suggests the use of asarray() but that did not work out somehow ...

I tried it like this:

```
with open("./test.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    rows = list(reader)
    audiofile = rows[12]
    temp_list = audiofile
    myarray = np.asarray(temp_list)
```

When I print the data type like this

```
print(type(myarray))
```

I get:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So that seems to be right. When I print the array like this:

```
print(myarray)
```

I get:

```
[' 0.06585693' ' 0.06663513' ' 0.066467285' ... ' 0.010253906' ' 0.011354681' ' 0.011835733']
```

So np.asarray() seemed to be the right fit. However if I now run:

```
librosa.display.waveshow(myarray)
```

I somehow get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/abc/Desktop/Project Python Audio/Datenbankzugriff.py", line 76, in 
> librosa.display.waveshow(myarray)
> File "/Users/abc/Desktop/Project Python Audio/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/librosa/display.py", line 2029, in waveshow
> util.valid_audio(y, mono=False)
> File "/Users/abc/Desktop/Project Python Audio/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/librosa/util/utils.py", line 300, in valid_audio
> raise ParameterError("Audio data must be floating-point")
> librosa.util.exceptions.ParameterError: Audio data must be floating-point

This surprises me, as the data is floating-point ... How can I preprocess my wave samples correctly to pass them to librosa.display.waveshow() afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that because of a mistake in my code I was filling the list with multiple arrays that had the symbols like this

> ]
> "
> [

inside of them, thus provoking that the list got mistaken as a character list instead of floating point. Fixed this issue like suggest in this thread:

[ValueError: could not convert string to float: id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420143/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-id)

Got the librosa.display.waveshow() function working with this code:

```
with open("./test.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    rows = list(reader)
    audiofile = rows[12]
    temp_list = audiofile
    temp_list = [(str(i).replace('"', '')) for i in temp_list]
    temp_list = [(str(i).replace("]", "")) for i in temp_list]
    temp_list = [float(str(i).replace("[", "")) for i in temp_list]
    myarray = np.asarray(temp_list, dtype=np.float32)
    librosa.display.waveshow(myarray)
    plt.show()
```