# Python:How to assign a list or an array to an array element?

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

My code requires me to replace elements of an array of dimension 3x3 with a list or array of a certain dimension. How can I achieve that? When I write my code, it throws an error stating that:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np
Y=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,4])
c_g=np.array([[[1,2],[2,3]],[[4,5],[1,6]]])
xx=[1,2,3]
var=2
theta_g=np.zeros((c_g.shape[0],c_g.shape[1]))
for i in range(c_g.shape[0]):
    for j in range(c_g.shape[1]):
         theta_g[i][j]=Y[var:var+len(c_g[i][j])**len(xx)]
         #here Y is some one dimensional array or list which I want to //
         #assign to each element of theta_g
         var=var+len(c_g[i][j])**len(xx)
print theta_g
```

In the code above I want to manipulate `theta_g`. In fact, I want to assign an array to each element of theta_g. How can I accomplish that?
Desired Output: `theta_g` which is a matrix of dimension equal to that of `c_g`.

Comment: can you mention your desired o/p ?

Comment: what is Y in your code? and provide in detail traceback.

Comment: Desired output is a matrix that has dimension equal to that of c_g. That is it is a matrix with dimenion 2x2 and the elements of this matrix are nothing but list or array.

Comment: Akshay I have edited my code, Y is a single dimensional array.

Comment: what is var? please give a full testable example. Also I'm still a little confused as to what your desired output is. You want an array, similar to that of c_g, which has what in each entry?

Comment: Maybe transform your sequence into an array? To do that, this seems to be a good way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41624067/3715676

Comment: @francisaugusto, Hi thanks for your inputs, I want the matrix theta_g to be of the same shape as c_g. Also each element of theta_g should be list. The main problem I face is in assigning a list to each element of theta_g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just specify the type of the elements of the array as `np.ndarray` or `list`, like so:

```
theta_g=np.zeros((c_g.shape[0],c_g.shape[1]), dtype=np.ndarray)
```

Because you didn't really explain the logic of assignment, let me demonstrate in my own example, where I assign some arrays to a 2x2 array:

```
from itertools import product
Y = np.array([0,0,1,2,10,20])
Z = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=np.ndarray)
for i,j in product(range(0,2), repeat = 2):
    Z[i,j] = Y[2*(i+j):2+2*(i+j)]
print(Z)
```

prints

> [[array([0, 0]) array([1, 2])]  [array([1, 2]) array([10, 20])]]

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot man! the first trick using np.ndarray worked! thanks once again!

Comment: glad to be of help.

Comment: Hi @Banana , also do you know any method in python to control the execution rate of a python loop? Lets say I want to run my loop at 100 herts or 10 milli seconds. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @AmardeepMishra hey, yes you can use "import time" and then call "time.sleep(num_of_seconds)" to wait somewhere in the code. But if you have any further questions on that please search for it first and then open a new question, so others can also give their advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html).

```
  >>> a = [np.array([1, 2]), np.array([3, 4])]
  >>> np.stack(a)
  array([[1, 2],
           [3, 4]])
```