# How to send output from a loop to a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this code

```
from opensky_api import OpenSkyApi

api = OpenSkyApi()
states = api.get_states(bbox=(51.3500, 51.5900, -0.6342, -0.2742))

for s in states.states:
    lat = s.latitude
    print(lat)
```

and the output looks like this

```
51.4775
51.4589
51.4774
51.4774
```

how do I make the output look like this?

```
[51.4775, 51.4589, 51.4774, 51.4774]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List to array conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868512/list-to-array-conversion)

Comment: The title of this question is misleading, probably due to false premises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
from opensky_api import OpenSkyApi

api = OpenSkyApi()
states = api.get_states(bbox=(51.3500, 51.5900, -0.6342, -0.2742))

arr = []
for s in states.states:
    arr.append(s.latitude)

print(arr)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
lats = [s.latitude for s in states.states]
print(lats)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a functional method:

```
from operator import attrgetter

res = list(map(attrgetter('latitude'), states.states))
```